# Blocking and Non Blocking Assignments in different Processes

Tags: verilog, warnings, system-verilog

I've some verilog code in which I'm using a variable "logic [1:0] internalSaveSense = 2'b00;", here I'm using blocking assignment and in some other process I'm using non-blocking assignment for the same variable "internalSaveSense <= 1'b0;". This is giving me a warning "Blocking and Non Blocking Assignments in different Processes", How can I resolve this?

Code for reference:

```
module someModuleName(in, out, qsave, save, restore);

input in;
output out; 
output reg qsave = 1'b0;
input reg save;
input reg restore;

always@(save) begin
  if(save == 1'b1) 
    qsave <= out;
end

assign out = (restore == 1'b1) ? qsave : in;

endmodule
```

The warning message I'm getting is:

```
Warning-[SM_BNDP] Blocking and Non Blocking Assignments in different Processes
Found blocking and non-blocking assignments for signal 'qsave'.
```

I tried changing the blocking assignment to(qsave = 1'b0 ) to non-blocking assignment(qsave <= 1'b0), but it throws a syntax error:

```
Error-[SE] Syntax error
Following verilog source has syntax error :
2138: token is '<='
output reg qsave <= 1'b0;
```

I'm new to verilog and don't know how to resolve this warning. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Replace `output reg qsave = 1'b0;` by `output reg qsave;`

Also the below `always` block will be inferred as a latch. Add an `else` or `default` condition to avoid it.

```
always@(save) begin
  if(save == 1'b1) 
    qsave <= out;
end
```

Comment: The code in always block in addition to be an inferred latch is also an implied latch with no correctly synthesizable behavior. `@(save)` should be replaced with `@(*)`.

Answer (score -1):

In a synthesizable Verilog code, always blocks with non posedge or negedge sensitivity list are mostly used to make combinational circuits. So if you aim to write synthesyzable code, use blocking assignment in your combinational block:

```
module someModuleName(in, out, qsave, save, restore);

input in;
output out; 
output reg qsave = 1'b0;
input reg save;
input reg restore;

//combinational block
always@(save) begin
  if(save == 1'b1) 
    qsave = out;
end

assign out = (restore == 1'b1) ? qsave : in;

endmodule
```